# How to display a set of colours that is similar to a specific colour?

Tags: r, colors, rstudio, display

I am trying to get a display of the actual build-in colours in R, rather than names.
If I use `colours()`, I get a display of all names. Now I would, for example, like to see 10 colours close to `"dodgerblue"` together with their names in the console.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try next solution:

1. **Install** package `rcolorutils`
2. You can find out, which **colors are close** to your, f.e.:

   ```
   nearRcolor("dodgerblue", "rgb", dist = 75) #dist - depth of search
   ```

**An output:**

```
     0.0             19.8             48.4             49.4             53.0 
"dodgerblue"    "dodgerblue2"   "deepskyblue2"     "royalblue1"     "royalblue2" 
        55.8             57.6             59.2             60.4             70.1 
"deepskyblue"    "dodgerblue3"   "deepskyblue3"      "royalblue"     "steelblue2" 
        70.1             72.4             75.4             78.8             79.8 
"steelblue3" "cornflowerblue"     "royalblue3"
```

3. Let's **look** to our colors:

   ```
   nearRcolor("dodgerblue", "rgb", dist = 75) %>%
      plotCol(nrow = 2)
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who is looking: I just found a second way to access a first overview:

```
demo(colors)
```

Displays all names in the respective colour, and also gives the plots displayed above for defined colours.